# Creating Search Form in Mysql and Adding to Joomla front page

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am am super new to the work of coding and such and I would like to know if someone could help me with my situation.

I would have a database called Booklist with columns (courseId, course_name, isbn, book_title, price). I would like to create a search form with a drop down box for course_ID on my homepage. How would I go about doing that and linking the together?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can [creating a search plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_a_search_plugin) for Joomla! CMS Version(s) Joomla 2.5 Joomla 3.1.

May this help you.